# how to set the child two div 50%, 50% with the parent div

Tags: css

I have following kind of pattern. How to apply a css changes for first and second childDiv  class  to 50% to the parent div

How do I set 50%, 50% to the child div?

```
<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
   </div>
   <div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This might be just me but I am having trouble understanding your question..

Comment: Just as Christoph shows. A percentual value in CSS is always relative to the parent div. Make sure you have set `parentDiv`'s width though.

Comment: By default, though, a `div` is displayed as block, so it will take up 100% width of its parent (which, if that parent is `body`, the width will be 100% of the viewport).

Answer (score 16):

```
.childDiv{
   display:inline-block;
   width:50%;
}
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/poikl/YEmT8/1/)**

Important notes:

1. don't leave whitespaces between the divs
2. You might as well use floats instead of `display:inline-block;`
3. If the elements don't align in the example, you browser does not support `box-sizing`, just omit the border then (it was for illustration purposes only).

Comment: i want to set 2 child div to 50%, 50%. i mean each child div should take 50% to the parent Div using css

Comment: @ashokcc yes, thats exactly what the code is doing. See my edit.

Answer (score 6):

There's a bit of a trick here, of which you need to be aware.  If you put any whitespace between the closing of the first div and the opening of the second, your 50% won't work because of the space being displayed in the browser.

There are a couple ways to do this.  If you are targetting only modern browsers (IE9+, FF, Chrome, Safari), you can use `inline-block`:

```
<style>
    .childDiv {
        display: inline-block;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
    </div><div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
    </div>
</div>
```

However, IE7 doesn't support `inline-block`, so you can go to the "old-school" method, using floats:

```
<style>
    .childDiv {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
</style>

<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
    </div><div class="childDiv">   // 50% width
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

If you want to ensure both columns are exactly the same width and still have a small gap between them, use different styles of floats.  Note this method doesn't require that you eliminate whitespace in your markup between divs, as long as the width you use is less than 50%:

```
<style>
    .childDiv {
        width: 49.5%;
    }
    .left { float: left; }
    .right{ float: right; }
</style>

<div class="parentDiv">
    <div class="childDiv left">   // 49.5% width
    </div>
    <div class="childDiv right">   // 49.5% width
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

set parent width to something first.

```
.parentDiv
{
width: //insert width of the parentDIV
}
```

And then afterwards set the childDiv width.