# Get divs side by side within parent?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to add 2 tabs in a wrapper div and am having trouble getting them to lie next to each other, taking up half the width each. I added the following css to each one:

```
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
display: inline-block;
```

For some reason they keep appearing beneath one another instead of next to one another.

I made a JsFiddle to show whats happening: http://jsfiddle.net/5zLoyc7q/1/

Can anybody please help me get them so they're lying to next eachother like normal tabs?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to set the child two div 50%, 50% with the parent div](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311604/how-to-set-the-child-two-div-50-50-with-the-parent-div)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not float? Make sure your `box-sizing` is `border-box`. Next:

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div>Hello world</div>
  <div>Guten Tag</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.wrapper {
  overflow:auto;
}
.wrapper > div {
  float:left;
  width: 50%;
}
```

`display:inline-block` adds 1px of whitespace to the right of the element. Also, if you're not displaying as border-box, you could run into issues with your box model in other words your 50% isn't what you think it is.

updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/5zLoyc7q/2/
make sure to clear the floats.

Comment: I like using floats vs inline-block. You should clear the floats but I feel like i have more control over the layout.