How to keep Text component width View parent width specified
Is there any possible way to keep the Text child full width in this example?
I want to keep the parent height and width value for other purposes. If possible, is there any way without setting the text width specifically?
import React from 'react';
import {ImageBackground, StyleSheet, Text, View} from 'react-native';

const App = () => (
  <View style={styles.container}>
      <View style={styles.quack} />
      <Text style={styles.text}>Inside</Text>
  </View>
);

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    margin: 100,
    height: 50,
    overflow: 'visible'
  },
  quack: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
    backgroundColor: 'red'
  },
  text: {
    color: 'white',
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
    textAlign: 'center',
    backgroundColor: 'blue',
  },
});

export default App;

I tried to check for solutions for this, but to no avail.

Have you tried width: 100%; for the text element? Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11311604/how-to-set-the-child-two-div-50-50-with-the-parent-div for more info

it was not clear what you goal is but i think this will help. https://snack.expo.dev/jS5Lgob9HDK4EUl4qRc0W
i used flex:1 in the text
